# Boolean functions computed approximately by k-CNFs and l-DNFs and the depth of trees

Tags: circuit-complexity

A well-known fact is that if a function f is computable by a k-CNF and an l-DNF then it can be computed by a tree of depth at most kl. Long time ago I heard the problem what happens if the CNF and DNF only compute f with some small error $\epsilon>0$. Is there a shallow tree computing f with a small error? (I am not sure that the problem was posed in this way, but this is the question I am interested in.)

Comment: What is the notion of error? I.e., what does it mean for a k-CNF to compute a function f with error $\epsilon$?

Comment: I think it means that the output has to be correct for at least $(1-\epsilon)\cdot 2^n$ of the inputs.

Comment: You can use the fact that k-CNF can be approximated by an exp(k)-junta, and same for l-DNF, but I suppose you want a better something better than exponential depth.

Comment: Smyth has shown a result like this: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=509907.509942